# SSRS Chart not rendered

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have hundred of reports with chart. Since we install SP4 on our SQL 2102 production server. All chart on our hundred of reports stop being render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We restart SSRS service, and all back to life.